# React app creating cart but not getting cart from django backend

Tags: python, reactjs, django, rest, django-rest-framework

Gooday everyone I'm working on an ecommerce project and I'm trying to build the cart for the unauthenticated users. Instead of using user id to identify the cart I decided to use session id to identify users currently accessing the server. It works perfectly in the backend but there is a problem in the frontend. creating the cart works but when I try to get my cart using the react frontend it returns an empty list.

models.py #for the cart

```
from django.db import models
from books.models import Book
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.dispatch import receiver 
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
User = get_user_model()




class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    class Meta:
        abstract=True


class Cart(TimeStampedModel):
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    session_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)




class CartItem(TimeStampedModel):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, related_name='cart_items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name='cart_products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    def __str__(self):
       return self.product.__str__()
```

Now I'll add my views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404 
from rest_framework.generics import ListCreateAPIView, CreateAPIView, ListAPIView, RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView, RetrieveAPIView
from .serializers import CartItemSerializers, CartItemUpdateSerializers
from rest_framework import permissions, status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.exceptions import NotAcceptable, ValidationError, PermissionDenied

from .models import Cart, CartItem
from books.models import Book
from rest_framework.views import APIView
import uuid
#create cart view
class CartItemcreateAPI(CreateAPIView):
serializer_class = CartItemSerializers
permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs): 
    try:
        cart=Cart.objects.get(session_id = self.request.session['nonuser'],)#Tries to get the cart based on the users session id
    except:
        self.request.session['nonuser'] = str(uuid.uuid4())#if it doesn't exist it creates one
        cart = Cart.objects.create(session_id = self.request.session['nonuser'],)
    cart_id = cart.session_id
    cart = get_object_or_404(Cart, session_id=cart_id)
    product = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=request.data['product'])
    current_item = CartItem.objects.filter(cart=cart, product=product)
    if current_item.count()>0:
        raise NotAcceptable({'message':'item already in cart'})
    try:
        quantity = 1
    except Exception as e:
        raise ValidationError({'message':'please enter your quantity'})
    if quantity>product.quantity:
        raise NotAcceptable({'message':'ordered quantity more than available'})
    
    product.quantity-= quantity
    product.save()
    
    cart_item = CartItem(cart=cart, product=product, quantity=quantity)
    cart_item.save()
    serializer=CartItemSerializers(cart_item)
    cart.total += (product.price)*(quantity)
    cart.save()
    data = {'message': 'success',
            'data': serializer.data}
    return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Now I will add the get view which is the view we are having issues with

```
class CartItemlistAPI(ListAPIView):
serializer_class = CartItemSerializers
permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
def get_queryset(self):
    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(session_id = self.request.session['nonuser'],)
    except:
        self.request.session['nonuser'] = str(uuid.uuid4())
        cart =  Cart.objects.create(session_id = self.request.session['nonuser'],)
    queryset = CartItem.objects.filter(cart=cart)
    
    return queryset
```

This whole code works in the API documentation but it does not work in the react frontend app. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: From what you describe, it seems that the problem could be on the frontend side. Are you sure that the cart item is correctly updated when it receive the data from the backend?

Comment: Yes it correctly updates. I'm working on the backend but the frontend believe that the error is from my side. Testing the API with drf_yasg schema and redoc the API works